# Contact Form 7 in Multisite

Tags: multisite, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using wp engine for my WordPress multisite project.

I created a Contact form using contact form7 in one site, the contact form not reflecting in another site, do I have to setup any configurations.

I want to get all submitted contact form details at a single place for that I am using "Contact Form Advanced Database".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that multisite networks share are users, Contact Form 7 forms will not be shared between sites. You will need to create a new form in each site